# "dass du recht hast" over why not "dass du recht bist"

Tags: sentence-structure

I was reading some German earlier and a friend said:

> Ich bin überzeugt, dass du recht hast

i.e. *I'm convinced that you are right*

but surely "to be right" must complement the verb "sein" i.e.

> Ich bin überzeugt, dass du recht bist.

Is there a logical reason why we use "to have" over "to be" in this instance i.e. haben over sein?

Comment: Is there a logical reason, why it is in English "to **be** right", when in German it is "recht **haben**"? Why should be English the better or more correct form? The short answer is: It's just the way it is. That's how language works. You can't translate fixed expressons literally.

Comment: *"but surely "to be right"* **must** *complement the verb "sein"* - The assertion as such is impertinent. English is **NOT** the measure of all things, and German, just like hundreds of others languages, does not and need not adapt to what's idiomatic in English.

Answer (score 3):

to start with: the correct phrase for your answer is the first one:

> Ich bin überzeugt, dass du recht hast

why?

because, if you use the phrase like this it means that you have (own) something, therefore 'haben' is the correct verb

you could rephrase and say

> Ich bin überzeugt, dass du im Recht bist

which is also correct, but it translates to a more legal point of view of the phrase like "to be within the law"

both `"recht haben"` und `"im Recht sein"` are very close and depeding often on the context which one to use correctly

Comment: Wobei “das Recht haben”  etwas completelly different bedeutet ...

Answer (score 3):

Such idioms are highly language-dependent.

If you insist on using the German cognate of *right* — *richtig*, it's neither *sein* nor *haben*, but **liegen**! Same for *wrong* — *falsch*:

*I'm convinced that you are right/wrong.*

> Ich bin (davon) überzeugt, dass du richtig/falsch **liegst**.

The other option is using the words *recht/unrecht* which are adjectives made from the noun *das Recht/das Unrecht*. But these adjectives are pretty uncommon apart from fixed expressions:

> Ich habe das Recht, **unrecht** zu **haben**.

The fixed expressions are *recht haben* and *unrecht haben* as they are made from the expressions *das Recht haben* and *das Unrecht haben*. Those clearly need *haben* as you aren't a thing but have a thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Ich habe recht!**

Der Ausdruck wird im Deutschen immer mit *haben* gebraucht.

(Ich weiss, dass ich recht habe!)

**Ich bin recht**
gibt es nicht.

Comment: Wir haben hier den Brauch, für die Antwort die Sprache zu verwenden, die der Frager offensichtlich am besten versteht - in diesem Fall wäre Englisch angebracht gewesen.

Comment: "Du bist schon recht" ist durchaus möglich und richtig. *recht* ist ein Adjektiv und daher auch für Personen verwendbar.

Comment: Ich habe gelesen, dass hier beide Sprachen opportun sind. So kompliziert ist meine Antwort wohl nicht, aber ich will es mir gerne merken für künftige Antworten. Danke für die Information.

Comment: Es ist *ein Brauch* - wenn du nett zum Frager sein willst, keine Pflicht. Schliesslich soll er ja mit der Antwort möglichst viel anfangen können.

Comment: Und möglichsr viel Deutsch lernen, was er so am besten kann, das war meine Absicht,

Comment: Wir können hier nicht davon ausgehen, dass die Frager Deutsch lernen wollen. Manche wollen einfach nur eine Antwort auf ihre Frage ;)